# Cell Referencing of Merged Cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been attempting to find a way around an issue I have with cell referencing in excel.

I am trying to calculate the cell value of B7 by the formula ,

B7= B6/B8

and want to drag across the columns like C7, D7, E7 etc. But the problem is because B8:G8 is a merged cell so I can't drag the formula across different columns.

[image: sample image of the spreadsheet]

It would be really nice if someone can help me out with how to do this more effectively without changing the formula each time.

Comment: Simple answer: don't merge the cells but write the according value to each cell.

Answer (score 2):

With XLOOKUP:

```
=B6/XLOOKUP(TRUE,$B$8:B8<>"",$B$8:B8,0,,-1)
```

This looks backwards to find the first cell with a value.

[image]

---

We can also make it spillable:

```
=B6:M6/SCAN(0,B8:M8,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b<>"",b,a)))
```

[image]

Comment: Excel *formulas* always surprises me. Great job

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 ideas:

a) Use a helper row below your row 8 (you can hide it) and put the formula
`=IF(B8=0,A9,B8)`. Use the value of that row in your formula:

```
=B6/B9
```

b) Write a tiny UDF and use that

```
Public Function getCellValue(cell As Range) As Variant
    getCellValue = cell.MergeArea.Cells(1).Value
End Function
```

Now you formula would look like

```
=B6/getCellValue(B8)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example I multiply B7 = B6 * B8 to easily check the result. I will replace B8 with the function OFFSET(...)
To create the formula I first created two NAMED RANGES, a) STEPING with reference: =6 whitch is the number of merged cells, and b) START_COL with reference: =COLUMN(SHEET9!$B$6), (you will use your sheet name not SHEET9) which is the FIRST columnh of the data, in our example it is equal to 2, and in cell B7 I put the formula:

```
=B6*OFFSET($B$8;0;INT((COLUMN()-START_COL)/STEPING)*STEPING)   
or
=B6*OFFSET($B$8,0,INT((COLUMN()-START_COL)/STEPING)*STEPING) 
(it depends on the region settings)


Then you can drag the formula to the adjacent cells.
```

[image]